# check date range with only month and year in Python

Tags: python, date

I only have `month` and `year`, and I want to compare if that **period** (of an entire month) is between two `datetime` objects. For example if I have these two dates:

```
min_post_date = 2013-03-07 00:00:00
max_post_date = 2014-01-01 00:00:00
```

And I only have year `2013`, and month `03`, it should give me `True`, `02-2013` should give `False`, `04-2014` should give `False` and of course `08-2013` should give `True`.

What would you recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: whats the format of your test dates ? like `08-2013`

Comment: I only have month and year, I could adapt the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first compute the two dates at the beginning and the end of your month:

```
from calendar import monthrange
from datetime import date, datetime

begin = date(year, month, 1)
end = date(year, month, monthrange(year, month)[1])
```

Then you can simply check that either `begin` or `end` fall within your range:

```
(min_post_date <= begin <= max_post_date) or (min_post_date <= end <= max_post_date)
```

This is assuming that you parsed `min_post_date` and `max_post_date` with:

```
min_post_date = datetime.strptime(min_post_date.split()[0], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

and similarly for `max_post_date`.